# CFD (Fluent) define a inlet for a tidal basin

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

I'm still pretty new in the CFD modelling world.

Can anyone advise me how to define a inlet for a tidal basin in Fluent? 
The water level and the velocity at the inlet vary in time due to the tide cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you might want to look at some of the ocean modeling codes that exist to model a tidel inlet.  The Princeton Ocean Model (POM) is one of the most well-known of these and is relatively easy to setup.  Other examples include

- FVCOM (http://fvcom.smast.umassd.edu/FVCOM/)
- ROMS (http://www.myroms.org/) and
- SELFE (http://www.stccmop.org/knowledge_transfer/software/selfe),

all of which have an active user community with examples.

Comment: Will not downvote this because it provides references, but it is more appropriate as a comment rather than an answer. Also, POM is very obsolete nowadays IMO, and has more of a historical importance.

Comment: This answer is too long for a comment, which is probably why it's an answer; comments are limited to 500 characters. It's also pertinent to the question.

Comment: I would like to simulate the water movements (circulations) in a tidal basin due to the tidal in- and outflow. After that I plan to make several adjustments to the interior of the basin to see how the water movements change. 
So you're saying this isn't possible in Ansys Fluent and I should use another program?